# liferay 6: reach main site from breadcrumb

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

We have liferay 6.1-ga2 serving a main site and several subsites. In the protal settings we set `/home` as standard homepage, logout-page and root-url.
Now if we navigate to a subpage `/web/projectFoo` and then want to return the main-site by clicking the link in the breadcrumb or manually typing `http://example.com/` (where `example.com` is of course replaced by our domain), we are not redirected to our standard-landing-page, but again to the last visited project.

If we explicitly type `http://example.com/home`, we reach our landing-page. But in the bread-crumb-line, the link points to `/`. And if we replace it via javascript with `/home`, there are still external links, that might point to `http://example.com/` (in another tab ...)

How can we prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now we fixed it. The problem was a wrong configuration in the site-settings:
The Home URL was missing a part of the path to the site:
`/home` is not enough, it has to be `/web/guest/home`, if `/web/guest/` is the internal prefix for the site.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you're looking for, but I'm really pragmatic in such a case and pick the 30-second-solution:

I always have a webserver in front of my appserver - typically Apache httpd - and would just issue an unconditional redirect on the URLs that I don't like.